# How can I increase my UV unwrap Resolution?

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

My apologies if this is an odd question but I recently created several image/textures in my UV editor in Blender in order to paint my textures onto them. This has been going well but I have realized my resolution is too low to draw the thinner lines I want to and not have them begin wobbling or cutting out sharply.

I know I could create new versions but I thought I might as well ask.

Is there a way to increase the images Resolution inside Blender?

Comment: Suggestion.  Start Fresh with higher resolution images.  The sooner the better.

Comment: you could increase the resolution in Photoshop then re-import and re-work what needs to be in Blender

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger

Thanks both of you for the feedback both of you, I'll follow one of these paths.

Comment: @moonboots Thanks both of you for the feedback both of you, I'll follow one of these paths.